# Increasing function between finite ordinals

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

I want to show that an increasing function between two final ordinals is determined by it's image and the set of elements in the domain where the function does not increase.

This is as far as I can get: Suppose there exist two different increasing functions $f,g:\mathbf{n}\rightarrow\mathbf{m}$, where $\mathbf{n}=\{0,1,...,n\}$, $\mathbf{m}=\{0,1,...,m\}$ with their usual order, such that $\textrm{Im }f = \textrm{Im }g$ and $\{i\in\mathbf{n}:f(i)=f(i+1)\}=\{i\in\mathbf{n}:g(i)=g(i+1)\}$. We can take a minimum $i_{0}\in\mathbf{n}$ such that $f(i_{0})\neq g(i_{0})$. Moreover, $i_{0}\geq1$, because the images of $f$ and $g$ are the same.

I want to know if this is a good way to prove it and how should I continue?

Comment: Yes, it’s a fine start. Since $i_0\ge 1$, you know that $i_0=i_1+1$ for some $i_1\in\mathbf{n}$. Consider two cases: $f(i_1)=f(i_1+1)$, and $f(i_1)<f(i_1+1)$.

Comment: Usually $\bf n$ is the set $\{0,\ldots,n-1\}$.

Comment: @Professor Scott: Of course the case $f(i_1)=f(i_1 + 1)$ can't hold because it implies that $f(i_0)=g(i_0)$. So we have $f(i_1)<f(i_1 + 1)$, i.e., $f(i_0 - 1)<f(i_0)$. Now, since $f(i_0)\neq g(i_0)$ we have that $f(i_0)<g(i_0)$ or $g(i_0)<f(i_0)$. But either case implies that $f$ and $g$ have different image. Am I right?